# How to update the current page to show new content?

Tags: navigation

I am currently displaying a list of MySQL database table names, such as table1, table2, table3.

Each table name will be a link; if users click on it, it will display them the data contained in that table.

One way I know I can do this is to create a Drupal page that contains the content of "table1", so that when a user clicks on "table1", they are taken to this page and can see the data of "table1".

However, this soon becomes un-manageable if I have a large databases with many tables.

I'm not quite sure if Drupal can work in this way, but I would like it so that when a user clicks on a table link (either table1 or table2 and so on), the current or a generic page will then be updated with the content of the table chosen and be updated with its content.

Comment: Are you doing this in Code (e.g. a module) or by hand?

Comment: Berdir, I am doing this through PHP code in a Drupal content. However, if there is an easier way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what functionality you are trying to build and if adding PHP code inside a Drupal node is the right way to do it. But assuming that is what you would like to do, here are the steps to achieve what you want:

1. Create a Drupal node (say the nid of it is NID) and add the following PHP code inside it

   ```
   $table_name = arg(2); // This grabs the 3rd argument of the page menu path (note: the 1st argument is indexed 0)
   print $table_name; // Replace this with PHP code to fetch and print data in the table represented by $table_name
   ```
2. When you are making table1, table2 etc links make sure the URL that they point to is `node/NID/<table_name>` where `<table_name>` is table1, table2 respectively.

Comment: Using PHP code inside a node is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @Sumeet, thank you for the response, I believe you have understood me correctly. Could you please tell me how I can find the node ID of the current node or any node? Thanks.

Comment: @Sumeet, I have found out how to find the node ID. Thanks. I will try and let you know. What if I have enabled clean URLs and have created a URL for this node? How should I reference the node then?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic list of tables/columns, then you can build this using PHP, you just need a dynamic menu entry that accepts the table name as an argument and then you can re-act to that in PHP. There are many books and online documentation available about how to create modules, try here for example: http://drupal.org/node/361112

If you have a fixed list of tables, you could build this using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views). If these are custom tables, you first will integrate them with Views, however.